# Array.push() in a Meteor.call() is returning array of index numbers, not ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

I am executing a Meteor method within a `forEach` function, and pushing the result of each method (a new `id`) into an array that is then used for other purposes.  I can get see each new `id` created (the `result`from each method).  However, the console is returning what appears to be an array of index numbers, rather than an array of new `id`s.

CODE EDITED TO ADDRESS ANSWER BELOW
In event handler, with two documents selected:

```
var selectionsFinal = [];
selections.forEach(function(v, selectionsFinal) {
    Meteor.call('copy', v, function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Result: ", result); //properly returns new id
            selectionsFinal.push(result);
            console.log("SelectionsFinal: ", selectionsFinal); // properly returns array of 2 new ids
        }
    });
    console.log("SelectionsFinal: ", selectionsFinal); //should return array of new ids, returns []
});
console.log("Selections Final: ", selectionsFinal); //should return array of new ids, returns []
```

Method

```
copy: function(v) {
    check(v, String);

    var valuation = Valuations.findOne({_id:v},{fields:{_id:0});
    return Valuations.insert(valuation)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is going to be extremely slow and, as you've already discovered, hard to debug. Looping over a `Meteor.call()` is not recommended because of the numerous server round-trips.

Instead of:

```
var selectionsFinal = [];
selections.forEach(function(v, selectionsFinal) {
    Meteor.call('copy', v, function(error, result) {})
});
```

Do:

```
Meteor.call('bulkCopy',selections,function(error,result){});
```

Do the array push in the method itself and then return the whole array.

Comment: Thanks Michel, this works great, much easier to implement for me as well.